# event click Handlebars

Tags: events, click, handlebars.js

Using Handlebars and OpenDatabase i have small problem. When you click on a link and nothing happens

my JS.

```
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM exhibition', [], function (tx, results) {
  var source = document.querySelector("#exhibition-template").innerHTML;
  var data = [];
  template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  for(var i=0;i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      data.push(results.rows.item(i));
  }
  var context = (data);
  if (language == 'pl')
  {
    var html = template({o:context,language_pl:true});
  }else{
    var html = template({o:context,language_en:true});
  }
  document.querySelector("#template").innerHTML = html;  

 }, null);

$(".exl").on("click", function(){
  alert('event click!');
});

});
```

and my html

```
  {{#each o}}
  <a href='' class='exl'>{{name_pl}}</a>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably binding events before the generated DOM is appended to the page. So, you can either wait for Handlebars template to be rendered (In your case this mean binding event in the callback from `tx.executeSql`). Or you can use [event delegation with jQuery](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html):

```
$(document).on("click", ".exl", function(){
  alert('event click!');
});
```